# Combine subdomain and folder location into one filter with Google Analytics

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics

I want to create a filter for a profile that looks at 2 things, a subdomain (subdom.mycomp.com) and a folder within the regular domain (www.mycomp.com/industrysolutions/).

Included is a screenshot of the current filter however it only reports on pages in the folder. I'm not sure if I'm on the right track?

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can have two include filters to a profile. Like you said, the data just stops flowing in, so what I would do is create a filter for the hostname (see below), and then create an advanced segment that looks exclusively at the request URI's you're after.

Include Hostname `subdomain\.mycomp\.com`

Comment: Thanks Blexy, but nope - doesn't work. Both filters work independently until they are put together. Then tracking seems to stop. My understanding of using filters in this way is that they work in order, ie. filter 1 fires, then filter 2, then 3 etc. This is why I was trying to write a regex for it. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Found this in another post but I needed to make some minor edits to make it work:

[image]

[image]

[image]